# list of figures and tables

Tags: floats, align, lists

I am writing my thesis in LaTex and the thesis formatting requires the word "Figure" to be present and bold in each line and left justified caption means caption should be aligned in next line

i.e.

```
Figure 2.1: Test Problem 1 Test Problem 1 Test Problem 1
            Test Problem 1 ........................... 34
Figure 2.2: Test Problem 2 Test Problem 1 Test Problem 2
            Test Problem 2 ........................... 36
```

Currently, I have

```
2.1 Test Problem 1 Test Problem 1 Test Problem 1
Test Problem 1 ...................................... 34
2.2 Test Problem 2 Test Problem 1 Test Problem 2
Test Problem 1 ...................................... 34
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{caption}
\textwidth  5.8in \textheight 8.5 in \topmargin 0.0in \oddsidemargin
0.0in \evensidemargin 0.0in \setlength{\parindent}{12pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}{}
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\listoftables
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables%
}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}{}
%\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{6em}
%\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }

%\listoffigures
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
%\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}{}
%\listoffigures
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
 \include{Chap_1}
 \include{Chap_2}
 \include{Chap_3}
 \include{Chap_4}
 \include{Chap_5}
 \include{Chap_6}
% \include{Conclusions}
\appendix
 \chapter*{Appendix}
  \markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\begin{equation*}
 A_0=\frac{-1}{e^{m_2}-e^{m_1}} \quad , \quad  B_0=\frac{1}{e^{m_2}-e^{m_1}}
\end{equation*}
 \include{reference}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please show the code that you use for creating the List of Figures? There are several ways of doing this, and the appropriate way for your situation depends on the packages/commands etc. that you currently use. Please try to make your code minimal, a short document with two figures in it and nothing else, and the commands for the List of Figures, such that the example can be compiled and shows the current behavior. For the figures themselves you can use `\includegraphics{example-image}`, then people that want to answer your question don't need your image files.

Comment: Thanks for your MWE. You have posted it as an answer, but that is not the right place for additional information, this should be added to the question, using the `edit` link below the question text. I have done that for you and flagged the 'answer' for removal. Also, you can format the code by adding three backticks before and after it (see the edit window to check how the formatting is done).

Comment: For the MWE itself: it is not really minimal or compilable. It does not contains `\begin{document}`, which means that it cannot be compiled, and also it contains `\include` statements for files that we do not have. Furthermore, the code as posted it does not contain any figures or tables (which was what the question asked about) and it does contain an equation (which is not relevant for the question). So please modify the code in such a way that it can be compiled without any extra files, that it shows the list of figures, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package as shown in the MWE below (note that most of the code in your MWE has nothing to do with your stated problem).

```
% lofprob.tex  SE 526765 Figure before number in LoF

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure } % put Figure before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1cm}     % extra space for extended numbers


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
THIS IS A FIGURE
\caption{A long figure caption so we can see how it looks in the LoF.
         Is this really long enough?}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter Wilson.....its great.  its working. Its also working for list of tables with little bit change, Can u plz tell me how can i write just a single line that is name of my university in old English MT font

Comment: @ShahidRafiq Glad that you got it all to work. Please ask a new question about the old English MT font.

Comment: i have already asked the question. the subject of question is                  ' Font(Old English MT) other than normal font in thesis'. i am unable to install any new font. kindly tell an easy and shortcut solution as i have short time

Comment: i have already asked the question. the subject of question is ' Font(Old English MT) other than normal font in thesis'. i am unable to install any new font. kindly tell an easy and shortcut solution as i have short time